# Azure Site Recovery Unified Setup - IIS fail

Tags: iis, azure

I've been trying to set up a Site Recovery Solution based on Azure, but still no dice.

I've set up the Vault, Storage, Virtual Network, but when i try to add a server to replicate to Azure, i can't get pass the gate. The Unified Setup tool fails on IIS check, i can't seem to find any information on anyone getting stuck on this point.

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2, we do have webservices for our development team and when i reported that i was running into troubles on the IIS check, i got that evil look of "don't you dare mess around IIS configuration or you'll blow up the whole thing".

So can anybody at least point to some information on how a IIS should be configured to pass the Unified Setup requirement, since i can't find it anywhere, nor have i find anyone stuck on the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show me more information about this error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest.
Not aware of any logs produced by the application. Although i can further clarify the mouse over pop-up on failed which states:
«Setup found one or more website configured on this server. Setup cannot proceed to install the configuration server as it needs to use the Default Website for the configuration server's IIS configuration. No websites should be configured on this server.»

Comment: Do you mean you can't install azure site recovery provider and agent?

Comment: I'm facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue around installing IIS in some configurations related to a bug caused by a hotfix.  For more information, you can see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aedfcc6e-bf5c-4e94-8ccb-f17478efe41b/microsof-azure-site-recovery-unified-installer-fails-to-install-internet-information-services?forum=hypervrecovmgr -

> In order to resolve this issue you need to have fixes mentioned in KB 3005628 installed on the server before you re-start the Unified Installer again.

You may also be able to fix this with a newer installer version, but that's not the "best" way to go: http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/F/43F07A59-151B-4684-916B-ECEAC9C0544B/MicrosoftAzureSiteRecoveryUnifiedSetup.exe

Comment: I'm facing the same error, I installed the fix you mentioned and it still doesn't work. Any advise, please?

Comment: Given that this is from almost 4 years ago, it's not something I'm tracking at this point - I suggest opening a support case and seeing what they say.

Comment: No worries, as the error message said, there was indeed a website configured other than Default Website. Removing it solved the problem. Thank you for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on windows server 2019.

Going to IIS Manager -Sites and removing the second website created resolved the issue for me as well.